# How to use js in snippet

Tags: javascript, code-snippets

I've been trying to include javascript in code snippet but it is not working. I tried to include my script in jsFiddle also but same result. Although, it works fine in my local.

**Expected Result**: Height of the element should change on hover as mentioned in js. Image should have the height same as the bottom of the read button. Below are the images for the same.

I am also including my html file as that is the working code.

[image: Before Hover] [image: After Hover]

Can someone please guide me on what i am doing wrong, below is what i'm trying to include(i'm using default settings of the snippet)

**Note**: Please do not tell me to ask it on `meta` [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326052/how-to-use-js-in-snippet?noredirect=1#comment356691_326052) is the meta link of my question and guy over there has proposed to me to ask this question here.

```js
function changeHeight(x) {
  document.getElementById('parentDiv').style.height = x.clientHeight;
  document.getElementById('topic').style.height = x.clientHeight;
  document.getElementById('hot-topic').style.height = x.clientHeight + 67;

}
```

```css
#section1 > .wrapper {
  /* Text */
  text-align: justify;
}
.hot-topic {
  /* Text */
  font-family: "Lato", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  /* Dimensions */
  width: 282px;
  height: 226px;
  /* Positioning */
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  /* Styling */
  background-color: #2f2f31;
  border: 5px solid #2f2f31;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px;
}
.hot-topic > h3 {
  /* Text */
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* Positioning */
  margin: 5% 0 2% 3%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Visibility */
  display: block;
}
.topic {
  /* Dimensions */
  width: 282px;
  height: 159px;
  /* Styling */
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(http://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2500x2500/HP_Hewlett_Packard_BV701AA_ABA_Pavilion_Slimline_s5_1010_Desktop_793042.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.topic:hover {
  /* Styling */
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}
.topic:hover + .caption {
  display: block;
}
.caption {
  /* Text */
  color: #bbbbbb;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  /* Dimensions */
  width: 265px;
  height: inherit;
  /* Positioning */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0% 3% 0 3%;
  /* Visibility */
  display: none;
  /* Styling */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
.caption:hover {
  /* Visibility */
  display: block;
}
.caption-wrapper {
  /* Text */
  text-align: justify;
}
.button {
  /* Text */
  color: #bbbbbb;
  /* Positioning */
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  /* Styling */
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  outline: none;
  /* Transitions */
  -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease, color .5s ease;
}
.button:hover {
  /* Text */
  color: #0c0c0c;
  /* Styling */
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  /* Transitions */
  -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease, color .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="hot-topic" class="hot-topic">
  <div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="topic" class="topic">
    </div>
    <div id="caption" class="caption" onmouseover="changeHeight(this)">
      <div class="caption-wrapper">
        <p>This HP Pavilion Slimline S5 1010, one of of the best machines Hewllett Packard has to offer.This HP Pavilion Slimline S5 1010, one of of the best machines Hewllett Packard has to offer.
          <br/>
          <br/>It has a 3.2GHz Intel Pentium E6700 CPU and a 750GB 7200rpm Hard Drive.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="button">Read More</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>HP Pavilion Slimline S5 1010</h3>
</div>
```

HTML file

```
    <html>
     <head>
    <style>
      #section1 > .wrapper {
        /* Text */
        text-align: justify;
      }
      .hot-topic {
        /* Text */
        font-family: "Lato", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 400;
        /* Dimensions */
        width: 282px;
        height: 226px;
        /* Positioning */
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 50px;
        /* Styling */
        background-color: #2f2f31;
        border: 5px solid #2f2f31;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px;
      }
      .hot-topic > h3 {
        /* Text */
        color: #999999;
        font-size: 1.0rem;
        line-height: 1.2;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        /* Positioning */
        margin: 5% 0 2% 3%;
        overflow: hidden;
        /* Visibility */
        display: block;
      }
      .topic {
        /* Dimensions */
        width: 282px;
        height: 159px;
        /* Styling */
        background-color: white;
        background-image: url(http://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2500x2500/HP_Hewlett_Packard_BV701AA_ABA_Pavilion_Slimline_s5_1010_Desktop_793042.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
      .topic:hover {
        /* Styling */
        -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
        -moz-filter: blur(1px);
        -ms-filter: blur(1px);
        -o-filter: blur(1px);
        filter: blur(1px);
      }
      .topic:hover + .caption {
        display: block;
      }
      .caption {
        /* Text */
        color: #bbbbbb;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        text-align: center;
        /* Dimensions */
        width: 265px;
        height: inherit;
        /* Positioning */
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0% 3% 0 3%;
        /* Visibility */
        display: none;
        /* Styling */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
      }
      .caption:hover {
        /* Visibility */
        display: block;
      }
      .caption-wrapper {
        /* Text */
        text-align: justify;
      }
      .button {
        /* Text */
        color: #bbbbbb;
        /* Positioning */
        position: relative;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        /* Styling */
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
        outline: none;
        /* Transitions */
        -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease, color .5s ease;
      }
      .button:hover {
        /* Text */
        color: #0c0c0c;
        /* Styling */
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #bbbbbb;
        /* Transitions */
        -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease, color .5s ease;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hot-topic" class="hot-topic">
      <div id="parentDiv">
        <div id="topic" class="topic">
        </div>
        <div id="caption" class="caption" onmouseover="changeHeight(this)">
          <div class="caption-wrapper">
            <p>This HP Pavilion Slimline S5 1010, one of of the best machines Hewllett Packard has to offer.This HP Pavilion Slimline S5 1010, one of of the best machines Hewllett Packard has to offer.
              <br/>
              <br/>It has a 3.2GHz Intel Pentium E6700 CPU and a 750GB 7200rpm Hard Drive.</p>
          </div>
          <button class="button">Read More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3>HP Pavilion Slimline S5 1010</h3>
    </div>
    <script>
      function changeHeight(x){
        document.getElementById('parentDiv').style.height=x.clientHeight;
        document.getElementById('topic').style.height=x.clientHeight;
        document.getElementById('hot-topic').style.height=x.clientHeight+67;

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The snippet works for me. Since you didn't explain what is the expected result, I'll assume that the content is supposed to change when hovering the image, and yes, it works for me. (I use Firefox 44.0 on Ubuntu 15.04).

Comment: Just curious, why do you have the exact ids and classes?

Comment: The snippet is running fine so there's not a problem with snippets. Is your code not behaving as you expect it to? How do you expect it to behave?

Comment: @MikeC sorry my bad i've updated the question.

Comment: @A.L its not a height problem. The code is working fine in my local, just not able to get it to work in the snippet

Comment: @a1626 OK, sorry for the wrong edit. The code behaves in the same way on my local computer (in a file, not in a snippet). Is it normal that `<div id="topic" class="topic"></div>` is empty?

Comment: @a1626 The current title *How to use js in snippet* is too broad, can you change it as something like *Changing height of an element with Javascript doesn't work in a code snippet*?

Comment: Here is the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8s4yym0z/embedded/result/ Note that the code is still in an `<iframe>`, that may be the root of the problem.

Comment: @A.L are you saying that even in your local the height of the image does not increase after you hover over the image. and yes the div is empty as it has background image. I'll update with images for better understanding

Comment: *are you saying that even in your local the height of the image does not increase after you hover over the image* Yes, the text and the button appear in a partially transparent box, but the height is the same.

Comment: @A.L can you tell me what error do you get in your console. when this gets executed `<div id="caption" class="caption" onmouseover="changeHeight(this)">` the function call `onmouseover`

Comment: @a1626 There's no error. What browser do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114551/discussion-between-a1626-and-a-l).

Comment: I think I (and all of us) were a bit confused by the fact that you asked it on Meta as if you didn't know whether your code did run or not and seeked support about that. But your question is actually: *"I know perfectly well how to debug, and so I noticed that the code executes well but the `height` property returns the same value every time. Why does it do that and how do I fix it?"*. It might help if you reword your question something like that.

Comment: @GolezTrol the thing is on `jsfiddle` if i open console i see error that `changeHeight` is undefined. Which led to conclusion that it is not reading js. That's why my question is around `code-snippet`

Comment: @GolezTrol but on further debugging with A.L we discovered that snippet is not even working on his local but if i pass him my html it is. so i guess the question should be reframed

Comment: @GolezTrol can you double check the snippet copy-to-local issue once. so that i can re-frame my question accordingly.